# Where to write the code to install the matrix toolkit?

Tags: java, hadoop

I installed hadoop, lapack and blas packages using this github site "https://github.com/NovanHsiu/JTSQR" .

How can I install the matrix toolkit in the same site?

I don't know where to write the code given for the installation of matrix toolkit java in this site  "https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java".

The code is:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a maven repo, so there's nothing to "install". It's a target for you to get a JAR dependency (which should really just be compiled into that code already)

1. Download http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.2/mtj-1.0.2.jar
2. Run `compile` script with the full path to that JAR as second argument